# Recursively list nested object keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have an nested object as such:

```
  options = {
    religous: {
      kosher: {
        value: 'Kosher',
        chosen: false
      },
      halal: {
        value: 'Halal',
        active: false
      },
    },
    vegan: {
      value: 'Vegan',
      active: false
    }
  }
```

It contains nested objects of varying sizes. I would like to get an Array containing the values of any `value` propery. So for the above object the desired output would be:

`['Kosher', 'Halal', 'Vegan']`

Order doesn't really matter.
I tried to do so recursively as such:

```
  getListOfLabels = obj => {
    const lst = []
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (obj[key].value) lst.push(obj[key].value)
      else return getListOfLabels(obj[key])
    }
    return lst
  }
```

but I keep getting a *RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded* error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The `for...in` loop assigns the `key`. To get the value use `obj[key]`. If the `key` is `value` add to `lst`, if it's an object, call `getListOfLabels` on it, and spread the results into `lst.push()`:

```js
const options = {"religous":{"kosher":{"value":"Kosher","chosen":false},"halal":{"value":"Halal","active":false}},"vegan":{"value":"Vegan","active":false}}


const getListOfLabels = obj => {
  const lst = []
  
  for (let key in obj) {
    const val = obj[key] // get the value
    if (key === 'value') lst.push(val) // if the key name is "value" push to lst
    else if(typeof val === 'object') lst.push(...getListOfLabels(val)) // if type of value is object, iterate it with getListOfLabels and push the results into lst
  }
  
  return lst
}

const result = getListOfLabels(options)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and check if the object contains a `value` key.

```js
function getValues(object, key) {
    if (key in object) return [object[key]];
    
    return Object.values(object).reduce((r, v) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') r.push(...getValues(v, key));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var options = { religous: { kosher: { value: 'Kosher', chosen: false }, halal: { value: 'Halal', active: false } }, vegan: { value: 'Vegan', active: false } };

console.log(getValues(options, 'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a succinct approach using reduce :-D

```
const getValues = options => Object.values(options)
  .reduce((acc, optionObj) => (
    optionObj.value ? [ ...acc, optionObj.value ] : [
    ...acc,
    ...Object.values(optionObj).reduce((arr, { value }) => ([ ...arr, value ]), [])
  ]), [])
```